# Infrequent ffmpeg in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg, containers, docker-container

Which service should I use for my Go program that runs ffmpeg in Google Cloud Platform?

The Go program downloads videos from my Google Cloud Storage and runs ffmpeg command to combine them into ~5 minutes mp4 file. I use this program only around 10 times in a month.

I thought of using a compute instance with GPU to get fast ffmpeg processing. However, because of infrequency of the invocation, I don’t want to run the pricey GPU instance for all the time. Cloud Run does not seem to support GPU.

What service would you choose for such workload?

Comment: Is the speed is important? What is the duration of your ffmpeg processing on Cloud Run today?

Comment: Speed is important. No, I haven’t used Cloud Run yet. Micro compute instance took 20 minutes for ffmpeg.

Comment: 20 minutes on micro + gpu, isn't it? DId you try without GPU? On a n1 standard1 vm

Comment: No, micro instance without GPU.

Comment: Ok, so you can use Cloud Run. You have a full vCPU per instance, and now you can even [use 2 vCPU](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu) (if ffmpeg can leverage several CPUs it's a good feature for you!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of the question, you can use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run#all-features) and you would only pay for the time your code is running.

You can also use a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview). Here you have a [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-go)

Comment: That has at most 2 vCPU with no GPU support. If there’s no better way for 1 week, I will accept this answer.